# show HTML preview in img tag

Tags: html

Can I see HTML preview if I have passed src to img tag as,

```
<img src="http://www.abc.com/uploads/reports/test.html" style="max-height:150px; max-width:150px"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not do that with image. Using [frame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp) could help you

```
<frame src="frame_a.htm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Img tags are just for images. That is the only thing they will display.